# Show jCarousel if number of items are more than 3

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using the jCarousel Views module; I want to hide the view when the number of items are not greater than 3. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JCarousel views as block display and then set a visibility condition by executing custom php condition test code (This will require to enable PHP Filter module)

```
$result = views_get_view_result('view-name', 'display_id');
```

Then you can analyze the `$result` and count the number of results.
Most probably you need to do ....

```
if(count($result)<3)
    return FALSE; //Would not let to show that block
else
    return TRUE; // Would let to show
```